# Business Process scope with Seam 3 / jBPM5

Tags: jakarta-ee, integration, seam, jbpm, business-process

In Seam 2, when I wanted to scope a component to a business process, I annotate that component with `@Scope(BUSINESS_PROCESS)`. What is the equivalent to Seam 3?

How do I integrate jBPM5 (or jBPM4) to Seam 3/J2EE 6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good question. The seam3 module it's inside the droolsjbpm project on github. You can check out the code from the master repository
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/droolsjbpm-integration/tree/master/drools-container/drools-seam

I recommend you to take a look at the tests inside the seam3 project to see what is there and how you can use it.
Cheers